# Model html5 canvas with SVG

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

The solution that I'm trying to achieve is to have a html5 canvas with bouncing balls inside. But the thing is that this balls need to bounce WITHIN the bound a certain shape (say a SVG map).

I've used [Sketch.js](https://github.com/soulwire/sketch.js/) to create my bouncing particles, and this can be illustrated in [this pen](http://codepen.io/filipemerker/pen/zKdNRY). But I can't set the `SVG` element as the `container` for the sketch.

So, here the question stands: how can I do that? Is there a way using sketch? Or there is another framework that allows this behavior? Or even any known live example of this?

My JS code, which is a fork on one of [rglazebrook's](http://codepen.io/rglazebrook/) works, is

```
var particles = [],
  particleCount = 150;
Particle = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = random(7, 20);
  this.rgba = 'rgba(' + floor(random(0, 255)) + ',' + floor(random(0, 255)) + ',' + floor(random(0, 255)) + ',' + random(.1, .8) + ')';
  this.vx = random(-1, 1);
  this.vy = random(-1, 1);

  // Draw our particle to the canvas.
  this.draw = function(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.rgba;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, TWO_PI);
    ctx.fill();
  };

  // Update our position.
  this.update = function(ctx) {
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
    // Bounce off edges.
    if (this.x + this.radius > ctx.width) {
      this.vx *= -1;
      this.x = ctx.width - this.radius;
    }
    if (this.x - this.radius < 0) {
      this.vx *= -1;
      this.x = this.radius;
    }
    if (this.y + this.radius > ctx.height) {
      this.vy *= -1;
      this.y = ctx.height - this.radius;
    }
    if (this.y - this.radius < 0) {
      this.vy *= -1;
      this.y = this.radius;
    }
  }
};

var sketch = Sketch.create({
  container: document.getElementById("brazil"),
  fullscreen: false,
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  setup: function() {
    var i = particleCount;
    while (i--) {
      var p = new Particle(random(0, this.width), random(0, this.height));
      particles.push(p);
    }
  },
  update: function() {
    var i = particleCount;
    while (i--) {
      particles[i].update(this);
    }
  },
  draw: function() {
    var i = particleCount;
    while (i--) {
      particles[i].draw(this);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Nosketch solution so no answer. In pure JS. Render SVG on canvas. Scan pixels with `getImageData` For each y row find the left and right edge (first from edge alpha!=0). For each y create array hold each ball size. Use the left right edge info above and below the row and check ball radius will fit. Set the left right limit for that ball size for that row. When animating test `rowArr[ball.y][ball.size].left` (& right), Fast and easy Could even reduce image test res pixel = size smallest ball. Much less code than reading SVG paths, and much faster than testing balls and zillion path lines.

Comment: @Blindman67 would you mind elaborate a little more on that logic as an answer? I'm very inclined to use this pure js solution. If you could give me more light on this, I can accept your answer.